# как эмиттить несколько событий от ребенка к родителю?

Tags: vue.js

**Menu.vue**
есть такой компонент `Menu.vue` является ребенком

```js
<aside class="aside">
        <img src="@/assets/logo.svg" alt="expocar" class="aside__logo" @click="hideAllLayouts">
        <div class="aside-links">
            <div class="aside-links__link" data-layout-id="features" @click="toggleLayout($event)">Особенности</div>
            <div class="aside-links__link" data-layout-id="advantages" @click="toggleLayout($event)">Преимущества</div>
            <div class="aside-links__link" data-layout-id="feedback" @click="toggleLayout($event)">Связаться с нами</div>
            <div class="aside-links__shit"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </aside>
```

```js
export default {
    name: 'aside',
    methods: {
        toggleLayout(event) {
            this.$emit('toggle-layout', event.target.dataset.layoutId);
        },
        hideAllLayouts() {
            this.$emit('hide-all-layouts');
        }
    }
}
```

видно что есть два метода которые эмитят два ивента `toggle-layout` и `hide-all-layouts`. эти методы вызываются при клике на соответсвующий элемент(при клике на `.aside__logo` эмитится событие `hide-all-layouts`, при клике на `.features .advantages .feedback` эмитится событие `toggle-layout`)

**App.vue**
и компонент `App.vue` является родителем для `Menu.vue`

```html
<Menu id="menu" @toggle-layout="toggleLayout" @hide-all-layouts="hideAllLayouts" />
```

так я пытаюсь подхватить эти два события. он не получается. гуглил, толку мало
Как передать два события родителю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй создать глобальный ивент

```
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
window.events = new Vue();
```

далее уже в компоненте ребенка

```
// component.vue
events.$emit('event1',{status: true})
```

и принимаешь ответ в родительском

```
// app.vue
events.$on('event1', (e) => { 
  // условия и тд   
})
```